# Exploit mitigation in EVM JIT

Tags: evm

Ethereum is moving to JIT-compiled EVM code: https://blog.ethereum.org/2016/06/02/go-ethereums-jit-evm/

As JIT compiled machine code has turned out to be a common attack vector in the base of web browsers (JavaScript) and Java, what additional security measures EVM JIT takes to ensure that rigged bytecode doesn't compromise Ethereum nodes?

Comment: I think this question can be merged with https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/9654/can-a-potential-bug-in-the-ethereum-vm-be-used-to-deploy-a-trojan-on-every-node/21392